# JavaScript does not replace the last symbol of the string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have try to replace a symbol in JavaScript, but somehow this is always only replace the 1st symbol of the string instead of replaced all the symbol.

**JavaScript**:

```
var note = "test'test'test'";
note = note .replace("'", "&#39;");
```

**Output**:

```
test&#39;test'test'
```

Does anyone know how can I can replace all `'` symbols with `&#39;` ??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use regex substitution and add a `g` flag to make it global:

```
> "test'test'test'".replace(/'/g, '&#39;');
"test&#39;test&#39;test&#39;"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `g` suffix for the Global substituation.

This is the right way:

```
note = "test'test'test'";
note.replace(/\'/g,"&#39;")
```

Check this: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kQnXL/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this note.replace(/\'/g, ''');